# Coursier vs Ivy, checksums & SSL exceptions

Tags: sbt

I inherited a Gatling project originally built against v3.2.1, and understand that version 3.3.1 has been released since the project was last actively maintained, so I updated that in the *build.sbt* file, and started getting "wrong checksum" errors on the command line (e.g. `wrong checksum: C:\temp\SSCCE\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.2\sbt-1.3.2.pom (expected SHA-1 4f8a5d7e2bf4c184d43ae9cc18466e23878ca5db in C:\temp\SSCCE\null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scala-sbt\sbt\1.3.2\.sbt-1.3.2.pom__sha1, got edf765410c981897fdce97c5629bbc0342509b43)`)

I found discussion of using Ivy vs Coursier, so included the lines below

```
useCoursier := false
update / checksums := Nil
```

This still didn't help, so after a little more searching, I cleared the project/null/Coursier/cache folder & retried.  This allowed me to build & run the tests, but all requests threw the exception *j.n.s.SSLException: failure when writing TLS control frames*, and I can now reliably switch between building & getting the exception if I use Coursier, or building & getting no exception if I use Ivy.  The project folder is not small, but I put together a [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) [project to demonstrate this behaviour](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdcF_Gpv_MLIa8KHQelHQ02YyQ1OqE7v/view) should anyone please have time to offer thoughts.

Comment: It seems you are using SBT 1.3.2. As a first step I would try to use either the solid 1.2.8 or instead upgrade to the latest 1.3.13. There were quite a few bugs in coursier and also SBT in the 1.3 line which have been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks. Was also pointed out that I had a duplicate version declaration in _build.sbt_: combination of removing that, upgrading & not using Coursier seems to have moved me on.